# How to find methods for active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I am getting a `undefined method`first_name' for #` error for the line

```
<td><%= User.where("id = event.user_id").first_name%></td>
```

Is there a way to look up the method for user active_record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to avoid having queries in your view.

The activerecord `find` method by default finds a record using its `id`. So, you can do the following in your controller action

```
@user = User.find(event.user_id)
```

and then expose it to the view like

```
<td><%= @user.first_name %></td>
```

The problem with your query is that it looks for a record with `id` equal to the string `"event.user_id"`. Also note that `where` returns a `ActiveRcecord Relation` and not a single record.

So, you have to use `first` or `take` to retrieve the first record. `where` should be typically be used for columns which are not unique(return multiple records).

Since we know `id` is unique, you can use `find` method to retrieve the record.

Hope this helps!